# Mac zip archives on windows

Tags: windows, macos, zip

What is the best way to open zip archives which are made on a Mac? Frequently when I open a zip archive the date file are 0 bytes, while the mac_osx folder is filled with the correct data files.

Its really irritating, so is there anybody who can help me with this problem?

Comment: This question and the problem it describes are not clear: 'when I open a zip archive the date file are 0 bytes'. Are you suggesting that ZIP files created on a Mac can't be opened in Windows?

Comment: You can view the zip report here:

http://pastebin.com/d515ec180

The fonts are zero bytes, except the files in the __MACOSX. When you unzip the archives, the unpacked files are only the zero byte files.

Comment: That's an incompatible font issue. I do recall seeing a font converter way back in the day that would convert. But seriously, get the new version of the font.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the files you are referring to have no equivalent in the Windows world.

```
2009-11-24 14:38        Folder        Folder  AG Book Rounded map
2009-11-24 14:38             0             0  AG Book Rounded map\AG Book Rounded
2009-11-24 14:38        Folder        Folder  __MACOSX
2009-11-24 14:38        Folder        Folder  __MACOSX\AG Book Rounded map
2009-11-24 14:38        134598         69721  __MACOSX\AG Book Rounded map\._AG Book Rounded
2009-11-24 14:38             0             0  AG Book Rounded map\AGBooRouBol
2009-11-24 14:38         34659         33343  __MACOSX\AG Book Rounded map\._AGBooRouBol
2009-11-24 14:38             0             0  AG Book Rounded map\AGBooRouReg
2009-11-24 14:38         31172         29835  __MACOSX\AG Book Rounded map\._AGBooRouReg
```

With the Macintosh OS, you actually have resource forks, and other hidden areas of the file...  The user doesn't see these areas, but the applications can store data there.  These fonts are storing their font data in a resource fork....  And windows doesn't understand what the resource fork is...

So, if you want to use a cross-platform font, use a TrueType Font...  The Mac will be able to read just about any particular type of font, so you don't have to limit yourself...  If there is any doubt about a replacement font, just test it in Fontbook.

Comment: Okay. Problem is that the font is delivered to me, so the sender has to change it. Will see if it's possible.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You want to stick with OpenType fonts, which are also cross-platform. TrueType fonts, while they work, are undesirable for various reasons that are longer than 600 characters.

Answer (score 2):

[7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) knows how to deal with the resource forks in a mac zip.

Comment: What happens when using 7-zip?

Comment: 7-zip appears to ignore the resource forks, so it extracts the file as you'd expect it to.